# Java was started but returned error code = 13

Tags: java, eclipse

I already searched stackoverflow for this error and found many solutions but either they didn't help or I couldn't find the real line in my ini file to fix that.

Eclipse worked yesterday but today It just went crazy and showed me that error.

The error:

[image: Error]

My ini file:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
```

Hope you can help me

Edit: (Java -version)

[image: java -version]

Fixed: Add the Line
"-vm pathdirectory to javaw.exe (care for x64/x86)

Comment: Go to the command line and try `eclipse -clean`

Comment: @Elliot Frisch still doesn't work

Comment: As a simple test, open a Command Prompt window, move to the directory that is pointed to by the -vm argument in your eclipse.ini, and run the *java*.exe with the -d64 to test for 64-bit support, and that it works in general.